# The library with $999$ books.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

> In the town of Capibara there is a library with books in $999$ themes. Since Capibara is an international town they have books in various languages. We know that for every language we can find exactly three themes containing books in that language. We also know that for every pair of themes, there is exactly one language which contains books in both those themes.
>
> Prove there is a set of $250$ languages such that every theme contains books in at most 1 of those $250$ languages.

Can this problem be transferred to a graph theory problem?

Comment: Is this from a currently running contest, or an old one?

Comment: Neither of those, a friend of mine told it to me a long time ago, but I've lost contact and haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Since $3*250<999$ how can the set of 250 languages be sufficient to cover all 999 themes? Each langauges covers erxactly three themes. Therefore, at most shouldn't there be only 750 themes at most?

Comment: @FooBarrigno, there are more than 250 languages. In fact there are 166,167 languages!

Comment: @Casteels: Sorry, I misunderstood the definition of the set of languages. If every pair of themes has exactly one language which contains books in those themes, are there not $999 \choose 2$ languages?

Comment: But for every language, there are exactly three themes containing books in that language, so there must be exactly ${999 \choose 2}/3$ languages. As I suggested in my answer you can think about this as a partition of the edges of the complete graph $K_{999}$ into edge-disjoint triangles. Each triangle corresponds to a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the scenario correctly, you could look at it as a problem related to a colouring of the edges of the complete graph $K_{999}$.

So let $K_{999}$ be the complete graph where the vertices $\{t_1,\ldots,t_{999}\}$ represent the themes. Let the "colours" be the languages $\{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_m\}$ and colour edge $(t_i,t_j)$ with the unique language in which both themes $t_i$ and $t_j$ have books in that language.

That every language's books fall into exactly one of three themes implies that for every $\ell_k$, the subgraph induced by the edges coloured $\ell_k$ is a triangle.

The problem is to show that one can find a set of $250$ monochromatic triangles, no two of which share a vertex.

**Added:** Here's a proof for your problem that I promised in the comment (adapted from the cited paper). I don't know if this is the "contest" solution.

So suppose we are in the situation above, i.e., we have a partition $\Omega$ of $E(K_{999})$ into triangles. Let $\Pi$ be a maximum-sized set of mutually vertex-disjoint triangles in $\Omega$. We want to show that $\alpha:=|\Pi|\geq 250$.

Let $P$ be the vertices used by the triangles in $\Pi$ and Let $S$ be the subgraph induced by $V(K_{999})\setminus P$. We have $|P|=3\alpha$ and so $|V(S)|=999-3\alpha$.

Since $\Pi$ is of maximum size, $S$ contains no triangles from $\Omega$. Hence, for every edge in $S$, the third vertex of the triangle in $\Omega$ containing that edge is in $P$. Let $X\subseteq P$ be the set of all vertices in $P$ which form such a third vertex, and for $x\in X$, let $b(x)$ be the set of edges in $S$ for which $x$ is that third vertex. Then $\cup_{x\in X} b(x)$ is a partition of the edges in $S$ and so $${999-3\alpha\choose 2} = \sum_{x\in X} |b(x)|.$$

Next, note that the edges in any $b(x)$ are mutually vertex-disjoint and so $|b(x)|\leq \frac{999-3\alpha}{2}$.

On the other hand, suppose $\pi\in\Pi$ contains at least two vertices of $X$. In this case we claim that for $x\in \pi\cap $X, we have $|b(x)|\leq 2$. To see this, suppose $b(x)$ has at least three edges and let $y$ be another vertex in $\pi\cap X$. Let $e\in b(y)$. Then there must be an $e^\prime\in b(x)$ that is vertex-disjoint from $e$. Thus $y$ together with $e$ forms a triangle $\pi_0$ that is disjoint from the triangle $\pi_1$ formed by $x$ and $e^\prime$. But now $\left(\Pi\setminus\{\pi\}\right)\cup\{\pi_0,\pi_1\}$ is a set of mutually vertex-disjoint triangles with $\alpha+1$ triangles, contradicting the maximality of $\Pi$.

Hence,
\begin{align*} {999-3\alpha\choose 2} &=\sum_{x\in X} |b(x)|\\
&=\sum_{\pi\in \Pi}\sum_{x\in \pi\cap X} |b(x)|\\
&=\sum_{\substack{\pi\in\Pi:\\|\pi\cap X|\geq 2}}\sum_{x\in \pi\cap X} |b(x)| + \sum_{\substack{\pi\in\Pi:\\|\pi\cap X|\leq 1}}\sum_{x\in \pi\cap X} |b(x)|\\
&\leq 6A+\frac{999-3\alpha}{2}B,
\end{align*}

where $A$ is the number of $\pi\in \Pi$ with $|X\cap\pi|\geq 2$ and $B$ is the number of $\pi\in\Pi$ with $|X\cap\pi|\leq 1$. Of course, $A+B=\alpha$.

If $\frac{999-3\alpha}{2}\leq 6$, then $329\leq\alpha$ so we're done. If $\frac{999-3\alpha}{2}>6$, then the above inequality extends to $${999-3\alpha\choose 2}< \left(\frac{999-3\alpha}{2}\right)\alpha,$$ which reduces to $249.5<\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is an integer, we can conclude $250\leq \alpha$.

Comment: Nice, do you think this approach or at least viweing the problem this way is better? I would also like a solution to the problem, in case you are willing to give it a try.

Comment: @user4140 This is actually a problem about Steiner Triple Systems and what are called *partial parallel classes.* Your problem is a special case of a bound given in the paper "A Note on Partial Parallel Classes in Steiner Systems" by Lindner and Phelps, Discrete Mathematics, Vol 24, Issue 1, 1978. I don't have time to write up their proof today (at least the $k=2$ case which is what you have here), but I can try to remember to tomorrow if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Casteels,looking forward to it.

Comment: I doubt that this is the solution in the contest, but I liked it nonetheless.